# Audio spectrum analysis using FFT algorithm in Java

Tags: java, audio, java-me, media, fft

I want to analyze the spectrum of an audio file in Java (ME).  I want to draw spectrum as some media players do.  But I don't understand some points:

1. Input for FFT algorithm, which I have to get from the audio file. I don't now what it is called, what it is and more important, I don't know how to get it.
2. Output: if input is an array (range?) I obtain other array, and it have range: 0-1, right (or not)? So what I have to do with it?

Answer (score 15):

You need a few additional steps in addition to the FFT. This has been covered many times already in previous similar questions here on SO, and you can find additional material by searching for "dsp", "fft", "spectrum", "spectrogram", etc, but essentially you need to do the following:

- apply a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to the input data (e.g. [Hann(ing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_window))
- apply FFT to windowed input data (for complex-to-complex FFT the imaginary inputs should all be zero)
- calculate squared magnitude of first `N / 2` FFT output bins (`re * re + im * im`)
- convert squared magnitude to dB scale (`10 * log10(squared_magnitude)`)

Comment: I want to ask you: calculate magnitude of first N/2 FFT output bins Squared or squared root ?

Comment: 10 * log10 (re * re + im * im) or 10 * log10(sqrt(re * re + im * im)) ? Can you explain to me source of original fomular ? I really don't know it.

Comment: You can either do `10 * log10 (sqrt(re * re + im * im))` or `10 * log10 (re * re + im * im)` - it gives the same result, but the second method is more efficient. `re * re + im * im` gives the magnitude squared. `20 * log10(magnitude)` is the formula for dB.

Comment: I want to ask you a question: I saw some spectrum analysis, dB result always < 0 dB. Here: http://www.blackcatsystems.com/pics/ipad/SpectrumPad.png . But the sample of wav file (16bit) has range from -32768 to 32767. If I use it for FFT, result is > 1, so that db scale is > 0. So where is wrong ?

Comment: A dB value is really just a *ratio*, where 0 dB means a ratio of 1. To have any real meaning a dB value must be specified *relative to* some reference value. So for example "dB re full scale" will be a scale where 0 dB = full scale and all smaller values are negative (e.g. 0 dB to -96 dB for 16 bit audio). Of course you can shift these numbers up and down and they still have the same meaning. Alternatively you can calibrate your system so that you use 0 dB has some real physical meaning, e.g. 0 dB SPL, 0 dBm or 0 dBV.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really understand more about it. Great help !

Comment: OK - great - well if this or any other answer is helpful then please consider up-voting it and/or accepting it.

Comment: I find a fomular calculate dBFS = 20 * log (sample level / 1111 1111 1111 1111) for 16 bit audio. I think it's right. So use FFT is needed when I have above fomular ?

Comment: Try re-reading the answer and the comments above one more time - I think you've missed some important points.

Comment: Paul, I think what you meant in your first comment is that you can either use `20 * log10 (sqrt(re * re + im * im))` (note the 20) or `10 * log10 (re * re + im * im)`, which would give the same result.

Comment: @tmandry: thanks, yes - well spotted and sorry to the OP for any confusion - I typed `10` for both - it should indeed be `20 * log10 (sqrt(re * re + im * im))` == `10 * log10 (re * re + im * im)`.