# FFT for WAV file and output to draw spectrum

Tags: audio, media, wav, fft

I have some questions about FFT. I want to use FFT to analyse frequency of WAV file, 16 bit dual chanel, 44100Hz. I want to analyse every 50ms, so that I have 2205 sample at the given time. So:

1. I have to use FFT for 2205 sample as input array data ? And out put is an array which has 2205 elements too ?
2. I want to draw spectrum of WAV file as some media player do, but I must use all of array or one value of it ?

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already, e.g. from earlier today: [Audio spectrum analysis using FFT algorithm in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627288/audio-spectrum-analysis-using-fft-algorithm-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't very clear, and I may have misunderstood, but I don't think you were asking how to perform an FFT.

But you should use **all** your data samples as input to the FFT, and draw a spectrum using **all** your output data.

Comment: I don't understand mean of all data along x-axix (hz), please explain to me. Thanks

Comment: So, effectively, you need to draw a chart using your output data. There must be many charting libraries available... The FFT is far too complex to explain here. All I can do is to refer you to reference material: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFT

Answer (score 0):

Basically if your sampling rate is 2205, the max FFT frequency you can calculate is half of the sampling rate without aliasing i.e 1103.

For drawing the spectrum you need to have all the values of frequency values and corresponding real part of the FFT values.