# Programming a Spectrogram using C

Tags: c, audio, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I am trying to make an audio spectrogram in C and am thinking about using the BASS library:

http://www.un4seen.com.

I searched over Google and here, but majority of examples are in C++. If any of you have any experience or resource regarding this, please help; it would be much appreciated.

So this is what I want to do:

1. Read from mic input.
2. Sample the data.
3. Apply Short time Fourier transform.
4. Then take the magnitude and plot it at the certain frequency.

Something like this:

[image]

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Spectrogram-19thC.png

If you can help it would be great.

Comment: If you want to see spectrographs, don't rewrite Audacity. If you want to create an application to do this from scratch, you are probably reaching a little high. (Not to mention that you didn't even specify the platform)

Comment: This is the second time today that this type of question has been asked - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627288/audio-spectrum-analysis-using-fft-algorithm-in-java/6633679#6633679 - you might also want to try searching for "dsp", "spectrogram", "fft", "spectrum", etc on SO as this whole subject has been covered in depth many times already.

Comment: 1-3 can be done easily, graph plotting efficiently on a embedded device is a headache. Try MathGL or gnuplot.

Comment: It will be windows, mainly vista and windows 7. #msw -it would be great if there are some pre-made libraries, i really don't want to do it from scratch, but if i have to, even if it takes a while i want to do it. #Paul R-  thanks i will search for them. Shreesh-I will look into that.
If you have any more resource you can tell me, mostly libraries, or tutorial (i doubt if any such exist)

Comment: @rave: you don't write anything at all http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i mean i do want to write it, but hoping it wasn't from scratch.

Comment: @Shreesh - who said anything about this being an embedded device?