# Sliding DFT in Java?

Tags: java, fft, dft

I'm familiar with JTransforms for doing FFTs in Java. I would like to do a series of short time Fourier transforms, and I've read that a sliding DFT is better for that. Are there any Java libraries that implement efficient sliding DFTs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked and couldn't find any good libraries to do this.  There is some C code [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663222/doing-fft-in-realtime) that I could try to translate to java, but I didn't find anything already done.  In the end, even without a sliding DFT I was able to do around 1000 FFTs of width 2048 per second with JTransforms, which is plenty for my needs, so I didn't bother trying to implement my own sliding DFT.

Comment: Still it's quite a shame there is no sliding FFT in something like apache commons.